# Is there a way to change the keyboard shortcuts of the jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, shortcut, hotkeys

I would like to change the default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> to reopen the datepicker to the enter key. I have my datepicker tied to an input and it currently does not change focus after the date has been selected.

Comment: The user's hand is already on the mouse; clicking the field opens the datepicker again.

Comment: Yes, but datepicker has several keyboard shortcuts documented at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/. I would like to know how to change those shortcuts to better suit the needs of my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just bind the key event separately rather than trying to change the shortcut key.

```
$("#datepicker").keydown(function(e){ 
    if(e.which == 13 && !$(this).datepicker("widget").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).datepicker("show");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this exactly, so helpful (: